# Getting error while indexing csv file in solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a file called data.csv in doc file.
while indexing the csv file I am getting below error:

docs]$ `curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/csv?commit=true" --data-binary @data.csv -H 'Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

```
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">415</int><int name="QTime">0</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">Unsupported ContentType: text/plain  Not in: [application/xml, text/csv, text/json, application/csv, application/javabin, text/xml, application/json]</str><int name="code">415</int></lst>

</response>
```

Can anybody help me out here

Answer (score 0):

Did you try seting the Content-type header to text/csv ? Because the error message is pretty clear in it's description

EDIT :

The init method of the `CSVRequestHandler` looks like this :

```
  public void init(NamedList args) {
    super.init(args);
    setAssumeContentType("application/csv");
    // log.warn("Using deprecated class: "+this.getClass().getSimpleName()+" -- replace with UpdateRequestHandler");
  }
```

I guess `application/csv` could work after all

Comment: How does the csv file look like ? also, i see the option to set the content type to application/csv (although i doubt that would help if text/csv failed)